# Looking for Object-Oriented Programming journal

Tags: oop, journal

I'm looking for a journal which discusses OOP and modern programming technologies.

Can anyone recommend any?

Comment: You're about 50 years too late to call OOP a "modern programming technology" :-).

Answer (score 3):

Try Uncle Bob's blog. http://blog.objectmentor.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Journal of Object Technology](http://www.jot.fm). There are some well respected people on the [editorial board](http://www.jot.fm/general/about/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a member of [ACCU](http://accu.org/) and have always been impressed with the standard of the articles in their journals.

A large number of past articles can be found [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c78/)